# Full width responsive drop down menu

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I have my responsive menu built and working well. But I want it to fill the 100% width of the screen until it transforms into mobile.

You can see it live here: http://pagedev.co.uk/iws/

Currently you will notice that the menu link drops down a line to fit the screen.

Is it possible to make the entire menu scale its padding to fit the width or will I have to allow it to flow outside the viewable area until it transforms into mobile style.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Lee

Comment: Can you just move the menu out of the wrapper?

Comment: You could use a media-query to make the padding a lot less big so the buttons will fit. The screenwidth you're talking about where the buttons break, is 100% anyway right?

Answer (score 0):

The menu is still in the wrapper. The wrapper gives the site a defined width. If you want the menu over the full size of the screen you have to move it out of the wrapper.

Comment: The buttons need to adjust their padding so they fit 100% of 960px. I don't want them to go over that size.